# PHP/SQL Find duplicate rows in a column, with the condition that another column is different

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need an SQL query to do the following task:

I have two columns. Column 'foo' and column 'bar'.

The query needs to return results if and only if column 'foo' has different values but 'bar' has the same values.

For example:

```
Foo               Bar
---------------------
1                 John
1                 Lee
2                 James
3                 Robin    <- the value '3' needs to be returned
3                 Sally
1                 Peter
1                 John
4                 Brian
2                 Robin    <- the value '2' needs to be returned
```

If I was to run the query on the above dataset, then both rows indicated withe arrows above would be returned, because 'bar' is the same on both rows, but 'foo' is different.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want using `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.bar = t.bar and t2.foo <> t.foo
             );
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It just says "t does not exist".... sorry, I'm a newbie at this...

Comment: @user3931836 . . . That is your table name.

Comment: @user3931836 . . . It is an alias in the subquery for your table name.